# posts_per_page showing only 1 post instead of 3 posts

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a loop that should show recent blog posts. The problem is the `posts_per_page` shows only one post instead of three posts. 
I couldn't figure out where I am going wrong.

I tried the following steps but did not help, but did not work for me.

```
ignore_sticky_posts = > true, 
update_post_term_cache=>false, 
nopaging=>true
```

The code is:

```
<section class="ftco-section" id="blog-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5 pb-5">
      <div class="col-md-7 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
        <h1 class="big big-2">Blog</h1>
        <h2 class="mb-4">Our Blog</h2>
        <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex">
    <?php if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) :the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 d-flex ftco-animate">
        <div class="blog-entry justify-content-end">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="block-20" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>');">
          </a>
          <div class="text mt-3 float-right d-block">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 meta">
                <p class="mb-0">
                    <span class="mr-2">June 21, 2019</span>
                    <a href="#" class="mr-2">Admin</a>
                    <a href="#" class="meta-chat"><span class="icon-chat"></span> 3</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <h3 class="heading"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 30); ?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Is this the correct way to loop?
The problem that I'm getting is that now I do not see any of the blog posts.

Comment: Please be specific about "did not work for me".  What did it do that you do not want?  For example:  "When I do ____ I get ____ but I wanted _____"

Comment: it seems like you are not actually displaying your content in the loop. The posts code should be displayed where this is: `// Display Content`.

Comment: Also, it would help if you posted the entire `blog-entry` div so we could prepare an answer for you that would be a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in your code, you are displaying your content outside the `while` loop. Also, you were merging the query arguments array with the `$wp_query->query` and those are different. You want to use: `$wp_query->query_vars`

Before you read further, make sure you visit the following links:

[query_posts() documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/)

[The Loop documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Your code should be something like:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
);

$this_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<section class="ftco-section" id="blog-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5 pb-5">
      <div class="col-md-7 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
        <h1 class="big big-2">Blog</h1>
        <h2 class="mb-4">Our Blog</h2>
        <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex">
      <?php if ( $this_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $this_query->have_posts() ) : $this_query->the_post(); ?>
          <div class="col-md-4 d-flex ftco-animate">
            <div class="blog-entry justify-content-end">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="block-20" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>');">
              </a>
              <div class="text mt-3 float-right d-block">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 meta">
                    <p class="mb-0">
                        <span class="mr-2">June 21, 2019</span>
                        <a href="#" class="mr-2">Admin</a>
                        <a href="#" class="meta-chat"><span class="icon-chat"></span> 3</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <h3 class="heading"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 30); ?></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata();
      else : ?>
        <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts found.' ); ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have posted the entire blog section now so that it would be easy for you all to help me. Please excuse me if there are any formatting errors. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I updated the answer with the latest code you posted. Please let me know if that is the result you expected.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Cornel, your code worked. Thanks a ton.